# Apache treatment of symbolic links under Windows

Tags: laravel, windows, apache, symlink, visual-web-developer

Does +FollowSymLinks work with Windows shortcuts? It seems it is completely ignored by Apache under Windows 10.

The importance of this is that, some web frameworks, like Laravel, use this directive to access storage folder (or any other folder outside the public directory) throughout symbolic links. Then, these features are simply ignored in Apache under Windows.

Could anyone, more experienced than I, conform or explain me that? Could you also tell me if there is any workaround?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts aren't symbolic links, that's not the same. In order to put a filesystem reference to a file or directory on Windows, you need to use [mklink command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) in either `CMD` or `PS` console.

As for Laravel, it ships with no outside dependencies, meaning everything Laravel needs to work aside from PHP itself should be located in the served directory, minding the path in configs. As far as I know, Laravel doesn't use any kind of symbolic links as it is platform-independent, meaning that as long as you have PHP properly configured and compiled with needed extensions, it will work anywhere. It even ships with a default `.htaccess` used for routing inside `/public` directory, at least in Laravel 8.

The way Laravel files reference each other is rather simple, check [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths). Mind they are also implemented as a part of filesystem in any Windows or *nix systems and behave similarly if not identically.

I propose to store the project as is in the config-defined directory and work on your code from there.

Comment: Yes, Laravel uses symbolic links. Try to upload an image using storage folder and not the usual image folder inside the public directory. For this very reason I made the question. Is there a way to use storage folder in Apache running on Windows?

Comment: Well, for this very reason there is a thing called Laravel Docs and its literally the first google result after searching for "laravel symbolic links" https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-local-driver. Having said so, there is absolutely no need to use "php artisan storage:link", it will do exactly the same thing as underlying mklink which I pointed out, explained the difference from shortcuts; it also won't be different from manually specifying the desired path inside configs.